# Glide JS not displaying images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, glidejs

I'm using Glide JS carousel in a VueJS project to display some images (at least 3), but what happens is that only the first of the three images are displayed, while the other 2 doesn't display anything, even though the `<img/>` tag has the correct *src* URL for the image. I've been trying to the debug this for several hours and can't find anything that might cause this bug.

```
    import Glide from "@glidejs/glide";
import FeatherIcon from "vue-feather";
import "./_style.scss";

export default {
  name: "DashboardCarousel",
  props: {
    imageSources: Array
  },
  mounted() {
    new Glide(".glide").mount();
  },
  render(h) {
    return (
      <div class="glide">
        <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
          <ul class="glide__slides">
            {this.imageSources.map((source, key) => (
              <li
                key={key}
                class="glide__slide glide__frame glide__image-area"
                class={`glide__slide slide-${key}  glide__image-area`}
              >
                <img
                  onClick={() => window.open(source.link)}
                  src={source.path}
                  style={{ width: "100%", cursor: "default" }}
                />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
          <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">
            <FeatherIcon
              type="chevron-left"
              size={48}
              style={{ opacity: 0.5 }}
            />
          </button>
          <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">
            <FeatherIcon
              type="chevron-right"
              size={48}
              style={{ opacity: 0.5 }}
            />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
          {this.imageSources.map((source, index) => (
            <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir={`=${index}`}></button>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: My image data was loaded after glidejs was rendered. As Glide JS got these image from props, which is static, it wouldn't change after parent component was updated (that's my theory).